# How to use the signal QMovie::frameChanged(int frameNumber) to emit a signal?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmovie

I want to use the frameChanged(int) to emit a signal when the currentFrameNumber is equal to the frameCount, my QT version is 4.7.4

`QObject::connect(movie,SIGNAL(frameChanged(int)),movie,SLOT(stop()));`

QMovieChild.cpp:

```
class QMovieChild:public QMovie
{

signals:
void newSignal();
public slots:
    void onFrameChanged(int frameNumber){
        if(frameNumber == this->frameCount()-2)
            emit newSignal();
}
};
```

Monster.cpp:

```
void Monster::Vanishment()
{
QMovieChild *movie = new QMovieChild();
movie->setFileName("./pikaqiu.gif");
QSize size = this->getLabelPointer()->size();
movie->setScaledSize(size);
this->getLabelPointer()->setMovie(movie);
QMovie::connect(movie,SIGNAL(newSignal()),movie,SLOT(deleteLater()));
QMovie::connect(movie,SIGNAL(frameChanged(int)),movie,SLOT(onFrameChanged(int)));
movie->start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a signal the class should inherit from QObject, if the class you use is QWidget, it is also valid since it inherits from QObject.

```
#ifndef QMOVIECHILD_H
#define QMOVIECHILD_H

#include <QMovie>

class QMovieChild : public QMovie
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QMovieChild(QObject * parent = 0):QMovie(parent){
        connect(this, SIGNAL(frameChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onFrameChanged(int)));
    }

signals:
    void newSignal();
private slots:
    void onFrameChanged(int frameNumber){
        if(frameNumber == frameCount()-1){
            emit newSignal(); 
            //stop();
        }
    }

};

#endif // QMOVIECHILD_H
```

Use:

```
QMovieChild *movie = new QMovieChild;
movie->setFileName("./pikaqiu.gif");
QMovie::connect(movie,SIGNAL(newSignal()),movie,SLOT(deleteLater()));
QSize size = getLabelPointer()->size();
movie->setScaledSize(size);
getLabelPointer()->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
```

Comment: The QMovie is still loop forever.

Comment: Wait a moment, you have to make certain modifications.

Comment: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status，what's this?

Comment: If you do not share your code I will not be able to help you, the code I show you is working, I just tried it.

Comment: Run `make clean` and then `qmake`

Comment: Thank you! I loop it once successfully.